# Hook word paste command

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I have a Word 2007 VSTO addin for creating document templates. It allows you to add special content controls for cycles or conditions. Content controls are bound to custom xml part data (using content control ID as a reference).

I need to allow user to copy and paste CC. Word automatically change its ID so I lost the reference to custom xml part.

Is there any way to hook Word paste command and access the pasted range - Content Controls?

Comment: Hi there, if my answer helped you & it was correct, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `Document.SelectionChange` event on the VstoObject of the document, you can get it by using `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document.GetVstoObject()`

Example:

```
using WordTools = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;

WordTools.Document vstoDocument = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
vstoDocument.SelectionChange += new WordTools.SelectionEventHandler(Document_SelectionChange);

private void Document_SelectionChange(object sender, WordTools.SelectionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Selection.Range.Text != null)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is going to help you,
Wire up the event XMLSelectionChange in your project. This event has following parameters

```
(Selection Sel, XMLNode OldXMLNode, XMLNode NewXMLNode, ref int Reason)
```

Sel.Range should give the range which you are looking for.